# Remove clear button on clicking any other field or anywhere

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I managed to show a custom clearbutton, the problem is that it will not be removed when clicking anywhere else or clicking other textfield. It is always showing.

Here is my extension:

```
extension UITextField {

    func clearButtonWithImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        let clearButton = UIButton()
        clearButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        clearButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        clearButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clear(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.rightView = clearButton
        self.rightViewMode = .always
    }

    func clear(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.text = ""
    }

}
```

and here i show the clearbutton on the method:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if textField == dateSearchTextField {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCalendar", sender: self)
             textField.clearButtonWithImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icClear"))
            return false
        } else if textField == timeSearchTextField {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTimePicker", sender: self)
             textField.clearButtonWithImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icClear"))
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

I want it to be visible only when clicking inside the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
self.rightViewMode = .always
```

With:

```
self.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
```